# Any good working example for webapp2 using http put method?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I would like to use HTTP PUT method , to send data to my google app engine application, any good example? I can't find any from google.

And my following example also not working.

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def put(self):
        self.response.write('test put')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/test/(.*)', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

And i got this error.

```
TypeError: put() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TypeError: put() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Means that the method 'put' was called with 2 arguments while you specified only 1 (self).

This should work:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def put(self, param):
        self.response.write('test put')
```

Answer (score 5):

you are passing the put an argument with mapping it like this:

```
(r'/test/(.*)', MainHandler)
```

the `(.*)` passes the put method whatever you use to access this urlpath after `/test/`.
update your handler like this:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def put(self, myarg):
        self.response.write('test put, myarg is %s' %myarg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using POST variable from request object

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def put(self):
        self.response.write(self.request.POST)
```

example usage using curl

```
curl -X PUT -d"x=1&y=2" http://localhost:8080/add
```